# AG Grid Show Percentage row totals in addition to Row totals

Tags: ag-grid

is it possible to show the group row totals as a percentage in addition to the count of the child rows?
[Group Row Totals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rd40q.png)

Comment: Can you add more details if you tried anything or looked for solutions and didn't find them suitable?

Comment: See [ask] and how to create [mcve]

Comment: Yes, but I need you to provide us with some code, if not we will not be able to help you

Answer (score 0):

To customize the group row you need to write a groupRowRenderer. In the renderer you calculate the percentage, and you can display it the way you like.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-grouping/#grid-grouping-callbacks